# Python website scraping for all of a tag using 'soup.findall'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm just beginning to dabble with Python, and as many have done I am starting with a web-scraping example to try the language.
What I am attempting is to gather everything of a certain tag type and return as a list. 
For this I am using BeautifulSoup and requests.
The site being used for this test is the blog for a small game called 'Staxel'

I can get my code to output the first occurrence of the tag using [soup.find] and [print], but when I change the code to the below I get warnings about printing a list as a fixed variable.

Can someone please indicate what I should be using for this?

```
# import libraries
import requests
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set the URL string
quote_page = 'https://blog.playstaxel.com'

# query the website and return the html to give us a 'page' variable
page = requests.get(quote_page)


# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in a variable ... 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

# Remove the 'div' of name and get it's value
name_box = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
name = name_box.text.strip() #strip() is used to remove the starting and trailing
print ("Title {}".format(name))
```

Comment: Could you add the error to your question, for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.find_all()`, you're creating a `list` of all occurences of `h1`. You simply need to wrap your print statement in a `for` loop. Your code with that structure looks like:

```
# import libraries
import requests
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set the URL string
quote_page = 'https://blog.playstaxel.com'

# query the website and return the html to give us a 'page' variable
page = requests.get(quote_page)


# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in a variable ... 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

# Remove the 'div' of name and get it's value
name_box = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
for name in name_box:
    print ("Title {}".format(name.text.strip()))
```

Output:

```
Title Magic update – feature preview
Title New Years
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.52
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.49
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.48
Title Halloween Update & GOG
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.44
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.42
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.40
Title Staxel Changelog for 1.3.34 to 1.3.39
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and a good explanation. Thanks. Bonus points for testing the output.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

That's because [soup.find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns a list not a string like soup.find

The snippets below should avoid the error and print any titles found in python 2.7 and 3.*:

Python 3.*:

```
name_box = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
titles = [name.text.strip() for name in name_box]  # loop over results and strip extract space
for title in titles:  # loop over titles and print
    print ("Title {}".format(title))
```

Python 2.7:

```
   name_box = soup.find_all('h1',attrs={'class':'entry-title'})
    titles = [name.text.strip() for name in name_box]  # loop over results and strip extract space
    for title in titles:  # loop over titles and print
        print ("Title {}".format(title.encode('utf-8')))
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Vantagilt the output for him was adding a 'b' before the string. This is to due to differences in the way strings are interpreted between python 2.7 and python 3. Here's a good [blog](https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html) on the subject.

The main point is by default strings are unicode in python 3 therefore the encode part can be dropped. In python 2.7 strings are stored as bytes and need to encoded explicitly or else we will see errors like:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Thanks. This was the first reply, and would have got the solution vote if not for the flawed output of the code, which when run surrounds the name variable with b' '. This results in [Title b'Staxel Changelog for 1.3.34 to 1.3.39'] as one of the output lines for example. Is this anything to do with using name.test.strip before name is declared elsewhere, or have I missed it completely?

Comment: @Vantagilt That is my mistake as I wrote the solution in python 2.7 interpreter and didn't see that issue. I have updated my answer with a solution for python 2 and 3 as well as some explanation around why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `attrs`, you can use the `class`.

As `find_all` will return the list, you have to loop over and format each value.

Python 2.7

```
name_box = soup.find_all('h1', class_='entry-title')
# name_box is a list, which contain all the value of `h1` tag of given class value

for name in name_box:
  title = name.text.strip() 
  print ("Title {}".format(title.encode('utf-8')))
```

Python 3.*

```
name_box = soup.find_all('h1', class_='entry-title')
# name_box is a list, which contain all the value of `h1` tag of given class value

for name in name_box:
  title = name.text.strip() 
  print ("Title {}".format(title))
```

Comment: Thankyou for this solution. It has both taught me a little about attrs and class and shown me  that the issue with the above solution was most likely the inclusion of utf-8 encoding as this code has the same issue with output.

Comment: Understand. Actually the code is tested in `python 2.7` which store the string in `byte`. For working in `python 3.*`, you don't need to encode the string. About this @cullzie in above answer already explained in detail. Anyway, glad  it helped you somehow. Updating my answer for future reference.